# How to compare data in table (before and after an operation)?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, diff, compare

Is there any free tool or a way to get to know what has changed in database's table?

Comment: There is no way to do this by default.  Check out my answer to a similar recent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337148/how-do-i-get-the-delta-for-user-id-since-the-previous-months-using-oracle-sql/7337524#7337524

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take a copy before the update

```
CREATE TABLE t2 AS SELECT * FROM t1
```

Run your update

Then to show the differences

use this to show updates:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
MINUS
SELECT * FROM t2
```

use this to show the deletes:

```
SELECT * FROM t2
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM t1 WHERE t1.primary_key = t2.primary_key)
```

and finally this to check the total number of records are identical

```
SELECT count(*) FROM t1

SELECT count(*) FROM t2
```

Note: If there are other sessions updating t1 it could be tricky spotting your updates.

Comment: This won't show you any deleted records, if that's what the operation is.

Answer (score 1):

Triggers really should be avoided but ...

If you are in a non-production environment you can set up a trigger to perform logging to a new table.  You need 5 fields something like this:

```
LogTime DateTime;
Table   Varchar2(50); -- Table Name
Action  Char;         -- Insert, Update or Delete
OldRec  Blob;         -- Concatenate all your field Values
NewRec  Blob;         -- Ditto
```

The Beauty of this is that you can select all the OldRecs and NewRecs for a given timespan into text files.  A comparison tool will assist by highlighting your changes for you.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Toad](http://www.quest.com/toad/) for MySQL very successfully in times past (for both the Schema and Data). I see it is also compatible with Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Try **[liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/)**, it provides the version control mechanism for database.